# Behavior of wait() and notifyAll() in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

Please note that this is not the actual scenario. I created a sample scenario based on my actual implementation, to make it easy to review. I am also already getting the expected output too. However, I need to clarify some concepts regarding the `wait()` and `notifyAll()` methods in Java. (In here both these threads will starts there run method at once in the main thread.) So according to my knowledge, since thread B is sleeping, because you can see at the initial stage reamingCount is 400.

So thread B will calls its `MUTEX.wait()` and continue its sleep until some other thread invokes a `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, then after the remainingCount decrements to 0, thread A will call `MUTEX.notifyAll();` to awake the thread B and `MUTEX.wait()` to release its already granted lock, and go to sleep until thread B notifies it.

When I call `MUTEX.notifyAll()` through thread A, won't thread B wake up and continue its task before thread A calls `MUTEX.wait()`?

I mean, you can see when thread A calls the `MUTEX.notifyAll()`, thread B will awake and check again if the condition in the while loop is true or false. So, since the remainingCount is equal to 0, thread B will exit the while loop and continue its task before thread A calls `wait()`. Won't this scenario break the principle of `wait()`? According to my knowledge thread B can only continue its execution when thread A calls `wait()`.

```java
public class A implements Runnable{

    public static volatile remainingCount =400;
    private final Object MUTEX;//Both class A and B holds the same object mutex

    private void methodA(){

         synchronized(MUTEX){
             
              while(remainingCount == 0){

                     MUTEX.notifyAll();
                     MUTEX.wait();
              }

              //Perform it's usual task.In here remaining count will decrement during the process.
              

        }
      @Override
      public void run() {

        while(true){
          methodA();
        }
     }
   }
}
```

```java
public class B implements Runnable{

         private final Object MUTEX;//Both class A and B holds the same object mutex

         private void methodB(){
              synchronized(MUTEX){

                   while (A.remainingCount != 0) {
                        try {
                    
                               MUTEX.wait();
                     
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                               Logger.getLogger(InkServiceImpl.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                   }
                      //incrementing the A.remainingCount 

                      MUTEX.notifyAll();
 
            }
            
           @Override
           public void run() {

                  while(true){
                     methodB();

                   }
             }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a thread holding a lock calls `wait()` on the locked object, the thread is added to the object's wait set and the lock is released.

When a thread holding a lock calls `notify()`, and the wait set is not empty, a thread in the wait set is selected and removed. Likewise, calling `notifyAll()` removes all threads from the wait set.

Note: threads can also be removed from the wait set by a call to `thread.interrupt()`.

When a thread is removed from the wait set and begins to run, the first step is to reacquire the lock. This happens before the return from `wait()`.

This will not happen until the thread that called `notify()` or `notifyAll()` releases the lock by either calling `wait()` or exiting the synchronized block.

So, while your thread B has been enabled to run, it won't actually return from `wait()` until thread A releases the lock by calling `MUTEX.wait()`. Likewise, thread A is enabled to run when B calls `MUTEX.notifyAll()`, but doesn't return from `wait()` until thread B exits the `synchronized(MUTEX)` block.

Comment: Thank you vary much for answering my question.